# Skype notification in gnome shell

Tags: gnome, skype

I have 11.09 ubuntu on my pc , I have installed gnome 3 . when  i login , I can see notification of skype in the tray , but i want to keep watching it, i cant do as tray hides by it self , in older version , in the panel i could keep watching it .

How to change the panel of gnome3?

how to put skype notification on the top of the panel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow (not tested) the comment at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/27/classic-systray/version/63/ , until it becomes an extension installable from gnome directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean status tray icon of skype. You can use [this](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gn/gnome-shell-extension-skype-status/gnome-shell-extension-skype-status.tar.gz) extension. Create a folder `skype.status@gnome-shell.morsi.org` inside `HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and extract `metadata.json` and `extension.js`.

[SOURCE](http://mo.morsi.org/blog/node/337)